# string split in bash

Tags: string, bash, split

In a Bash script I would like to split a line into pieces and put them into an array.

The line:

ParisABFranceABEurope

I would like to split them in an array like this (with AB):

```
array[0] = Paris
array[1] = France
array[2] = Europe
```

I would like to use simple code, the command's speed doesn't matter. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string on a delimiter in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Here is one that doesn't need sub-shells (i.e. it's all built-in). You'll need to pick a single delimiter character (here `@`) that can't appear in the data:

```
str='ParisABFranceABEurope'
IFS='@' read -r -a words <<< "${str//AB/@}"

echo "${words[0]}"
echo "${words[1]}"
echo "${words[2]}"
```

Drum roll, please...

```
$ source foo.sh
Paris
France
Europe
```

Comment: Nicely done; to encourage good habits, please double-quote `${words[0]}`, ..., and use `-r` with `read`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$declare -a array=($(echo "ParisABFranceABEurope" | awk -F 'AB' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'))
$ echo "${array[@]}"
Paris France Europe
```

Comment: This works for the sample input, but the caveat is that it makes the resulting tokens subject to pathname expansion.